# Get number of emails in specific directory on mail server

Tags: email, gmail

I am trying to find a way to connect to a mail server and find out how many emails there are in a specific directory. In this specific case, it is the Spam directory in my Gmail account. I am not trying to download the emails in this directory but just count or query the number. I also need to be able to do this from the Terminal.

I remember, a number of years ago, reading a way to do this by using the POP3 protocol to query a specific directory and get a few statistics about that it, including the number of emails. I just tried to find them again but haven't been able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find another easier way of doing what I need using Curl and the IMAP protocol:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com" --user "<email address>":"<password>" -X 'STATUS [Gmail]/Spam (MESSAGES)'
```

Stdout for this command will be the following (with X being the number of messages present, both read and unread):

```
* STATUS "[Gmail]/Spam" (MESSAGES X)
```

Comment: For Inbox, change the last part of the command above ('STATUS [Gmail]/Spam (MESSAGES)') to 'STATUS Inbox (MESSAGES)'

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to gmail is tricky as google tries to discourage people from using other mail clients than web browsers. First you need to [visit google account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) and check the setting that allows "*apps & devices to access your account in a less secure way*". Google then will frequently spam your mailbox asking to uncheck this.

Now, to the point.
To access `gmail` via imap (google discourages pop protocol and so do I) you need to use `993` port and add control line feed to `openssl` option. Spam folder is `[Gmail]/Spam` and, as I understood, you want to get its next unique ID, so the typical session should look like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = Google Internet Authority G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = imap.gmail.com
verify return:1
---

[...]

---
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 10.0.0.1 n9mb133f65154lxl

a1 LOGIN <user> <password>
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
a1 OK user@gmail.com authenticated (Success)

a2 STATUS "[Gmail]/Spam" (UIDNEXT)
* STATUS "[Gmail]/Spam" (UIDNEXT 2127)
a2 OK Success

a3 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
a3 OK 73 good day (Success)
read:errno=0
```

The commands actually typed by you are those started with tags `aN`. Tags are obligatory by imap protocol, so don't forget about them; they don't need to be in `aN` form, any string is fine. Obviously change `<user>` and `<password>` to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it on this way:

```
telnet mailhost 110 >/tmp/outfile <<EOF
USER username
PASS password
LIST
QUIT
EOF
NMSG=$(tail -3 /tmp/outfile|awk '{print $1;exit}')
```

And you will get in variable `NMSG` the number of the messages. I am not sure pop can deal with mail folders. It just report messages in mailbox.
In case of SSL/TLS POP3 implementation you can use code like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect mailhost:995 >/tmp/outfile <<EOF
USER username
PASS password
LIST
QUIT
EOF
NMSG=$(tail -3 /tmp/outfile|awk '{print $1;exit}')
```

If your mail delivery software mark SPAM messages adding "SPAM" word in subject you can try as last line in script something like:

```
NMSG=$(grep SPAM /tmp/outfile|wc -l)
```